# Sample projects for sharepoint 2010 in codeplex.com

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, project

I want any sample projects to learn more about sharepoint 2010. I searched in google. But didn't find any downloadable projects. I think there would be in [codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com), can any one suggest me the names of the projects or links to download in codeplex or any other site. There are lot of projects in codeplex, so picking a project is difficult. if any one knows the titles or already downloaded, my job would be much easy and useful to many people also who are searching for similar kind of thing. This question may be off-topic but, i have no other option to get help.

Thanks,

Comment: what kind of project you need webpart/fieldtype/workflow/listdefination etc?

Comment: Can't we find a complete set of project means.. health care project, financial project etc. webpart/fieldtyp/workflow projects are available directly from code plex.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provide the [101 Code Samples for SharePoint 2010](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2010-101-Code-da251182) - download them and study them and you will be a lot smarter ;-)

> Each code sample is part of the SharePoint 2010 101 code samples
>   project. These samples are provided so that you can incorporate them
>   directly in your code.
>
> Each code sample consists of a standalone
>   project created in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and demonstrates a
>   distinct feature or feature set. Each sample includes comments
>   describing the sample and the expected results. Each sample also
>   contains comments that explain how to set up your environment so that
>   the sample code runs, where necessary.
>
> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 gives you the tools needed to create powerful applications. These
>   managed code (C#, VB.NET, JavaScript, XML) samples can assist you in
>   creating your own applications that perform specific functions or as a
>   starting point to create more complex solutions.

Comment: @moontear... thanks for your information. I have these samples. My intention is to look sharepoint implementations as one project. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Every sample could be a small project. Each codeplex project is a project in itself. You will not find a "financial project" or something like that. You will find a "webpart" project. In the end a financial project consists out of many webparts.